# How to list all existing values for a field across site

Tags: entry, field, loop

I have a huge set of entries which have a lot of fields. Say, the entry type is a 'book' and fields are 'keywords', 'year', 'authors', etc.

Now I'm building a filter form which would allow user to output entries by field values. On frontend side this form contains generally inputs with datalist tags which should contain all of a specific field's values. For example, the datalist for the 'Year' search input should contain all years ever set for all the books on the site.

How do I do this efficiently, how do we list all existing values for a field? [This answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/5102/3838) proposes to loop through each entry every time and collect the field values used in entries in an array - but when I tried to do it I hit the memory exhausted problem.

An example code of the approach which leads to memory being exhausted:

```
{% set years = [] %}
{% for book in craft.entries.section('books').year.order('year desc').limit(0) %}
    {% if book.year not in years %}
        {% set years = years|merge([book.year]) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% for year in years %}
    <li>{{ year }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please let me know if there's anything unclear with my answer @certainlyakey.

Comment: Thank you @carics. I think everything is clear, I just need to test it. Is the variables subfolder enough to make the plugin work?

Comment: Yes, a [primary plugin class](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/setting-things-up#your-primary-plugin-class) and a [template variable class](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/variables) in variables/

Answer (score 2):

To get better performance you need to switch to using PHP. All you need is a [MyPluginVariable class](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/variables)
to do some logic in PHP and make the result available to your Twig templates. It's really not very complicated.

From your variable class you'd use [Yii Query Builder](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/database) to create your SQL statements. There's now two ways to approach this.

1. Start from fresh using [`craft()->db->createCommand()`](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/database) and add all the necessary parameters manually (section, locale, limit,...).
2. Pass a Craft [criteria model](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel) with all parameters already set to the [`buildElementsQuery`](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/ElementsService#buildElementsQuery-detail) method to convert it.

I'll show you exampe code for the second approach. From your template prepare a criteria model as usual, set the section and other parameters. Then call the new template function we are going to create soon, which will take two parameters, a criteria model and a field handle.

```
{% set criteria = craft.entries.section('books').order('myYearsField desc').limit(null) %}
{% set years = craft.businessLogic.getDistinctValues(criteria, 'myYearsField') %}
```

Now we need to create this `getDistinctValues` method in our variable class.

```
public function getDistinctValues($criteria, $column)
{
    $query = craft()->elements->buildElementsQuery($criteria);

    // Modify query to select just our `$column` column, only distinct values
    $query->selectDistinct("field_{$column}");

    // Query for one column only and return the result
    return $query->queryColumn();
}
```

That [`selectDistinct`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#selectDistinct-detail) parameter overrides the `select` set by Craft in the initial criteria model. Performance should be way better, you're querying for a single column only, only for distinct values and you don't populate entry models which you do not need anyways.